# Unable to update the boolean value using retrofit post

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to make post request using retrofit:

```
class PostContentModel {

    @SerializedName("createdBy")
    var createdBy: UserDTO? = null

    @SerializedName("postID")
    var postID: String? = null

    @SerializedName("isMemory")
    var isMemory: Boolean?= false
}
```

```
    @POST("v1/posts")
    fun postContent(@Body map: PostContentModel?): Call<ResponseBody>
```

now in my main activity when i try sending data using retrofit, the createBy and and postID fields are getting updated but the isMemory(boolean) is not getting updated if i set it to true.

```
    val postContentModel: PostContentModel? = PostContentModel()

postContentModel?.createdBy = "xyz"
postContentModel?.postID= "5"
postContentModel?.isMemory= true
ApiCall.postContent(postContentModel)
```

so now when i check the server the first 2 values have updated but the isMemory is still left at default false value which was preset in the server.

Comment: May be your request attribute not match with api. And Data are passing correctly to api.can you add your request json from postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try calss as data class

```
 data class PostContentModel (

    var createdBy: UserDTO? = null,

    var postID: String? = null,

    var isMemory: Boolean?= null,
)
```

you can use apply scope function to add modification on object

```
    val postContentModel=PostContentModel().apply {
        createdBy=null
        postID=""
        isMemory=true
    }
```

will work with you